# Getting a TypeScript scoping error with .indexOf

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I convert this to proper TypeScript (Angular2) ?

```
import { UtilsService } from '../providers/utils-service';

@Injectable()
export class ImagesService {

    constructor(
          private connectionStatus: ConnectionStatus
        , private UrlExists: UrlExists
        , private storageService: LocalStorageService
        , private UtilsService: UtilsService
    ) {
    }

    usualTreatment(prodata, gotANewDB) {
        if (str.indexOf(suffix, this.length - suffix.length) === -1) {
        ...
```

because I get a scope error :

```
Typescript Error
Property 'length' does not exist on type 'ImagesService'.
src/providers/images-service.ts
for (var str in imagesUrls) {
    if (str.indexOf(suffix, this.length
```

Comment: did you have this.length property in ImagesService class

Comment: we need more context, what is wrapping that `if` statement , a method, a function, an arrow function ? Please, provide more code, your whole class if needed.

Comment: please post code for `images-service.ts`

Comment: Sorry, I added some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean

```
if (str.indexOf(suffix, str.length - suffix.length) === -1) {
                        ^^^
```